# tableView.insertRows throws NSException, but not when `insertRows` at `[[0,0]]`

Tags: ios, swift

I am following a modified (simplified) version of the tutorial very much like what is found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1

and here is my `UITableViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var newsTableView: UITableView!

    /*
        MARK: properties
    */
    var news = NewsData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dummyNewData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return news.length()
    }


    // here we communicate with parts of the app that owns the data
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView
                           , cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
                           ) -> UITableViewCell {

        // note here we're using the native cell class
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsCell", for: indexPath)
        // Configure the cell...
        let row : Int = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = news.read(idx: row)
        return cell
    }


    // MARK: Navigation ****************************************************************

    // accept message from CreateNewViewController
    @IBAction func unwindToCreateNewView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){

        if let srcViewController = sender.source as? CreateNewsViewController
        , let msg = srcViewController.message {

            // push into news instance and display on table
            news.write(msg: msg)
            let idxPath = IndexPath(row: news.length(), section: 1)

            // tableView.insertRows(at: [idxPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [[0,0]], with: .automatic)

            print("unwound with message: ", msg, idxPath)
            print("news now has n pieces of news: ", news.length())
            print("the last news is: ", news.peek())

        }

    }


    /*
        @DEBUG: debugging functions that display things on screen **************************
    */
    // push some values into new data
    private func dummyNewData(){

        print("dummyNewData")
        news.write(msg: "hello world first message")
        news.write(msg: "hello world second message")
        news.write(msg: "hello world third message")
    }

}
```

The problem is in the function `unwindToCreateNewView`:

```
let idxPath = IndexPath(row: news.length(), section: 1)
tableView.insertRows(at: [idxPath], with: .automatic)
```

where `news.length()` gives me an `Int` that is basically `someArray.count`.

When I `insertRows(at: [idxPath] ...)`, I get error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

But when I just hard code it to do:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [[0,0]], with: .automatic)
```

It works just fine. And on the simulator I see new messages are inserted below the previous ones. What gives?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the exception text; it will tell you what went wrong, but in your first code your are inserting into section 1, but in your second code you are inserting into section 0. your table only has 1 section, so inserting into the second section (section 1) won't work

Comment: You've hardcoded the number of sections as 1.  Since the section numbers begin at 0, any attempt to insert a row in section 1 will trigger an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an "off by one" problem with the following code:

```
news.write(msg: msg)
let idxPath = IndexPath(row: news.length(), section: 1)
```

Let's say that just before this code is called, you have no items in `news`. This means there are 0 rows. When you want to add a new row, you need to insert at row 0 since row numbers start at 0.

Calling `news.write(msg: msg)` add the new item and its length is now 1.

Calling `IndexPath(row: news.length(), section: 1)` sets the row to a value of 1 but it needs to be 0.

One simple solution is to swap those two lines:

```
let idxPath = IndexPath(row: news.length(), section: 1)
news.write(msg: msg)
```

That will create the index path with the proper row number.

And since this is the first (and only) section, the section number needs to be changed to 0 in addition to the above change.

```
let idxPath = IndexPath(row: news.length(), section: 0)
news.write(msg: msg)
```